# Backup mysql database from Java using mysqldump failed

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring-boot, database-backups

I am using mysqldump like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD DBNAME > /path/to/location/backup.sql");
```

in order to dump it into my local files, my java program is deployed using kubernetes.
Here is my code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/testDumping", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public Object test(@RequestBody Map<String,Object> params) throws IOException {
    String runStatement = (String)params.get("runStatement");
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process exec = runtime.exec(runStatement);
    return exec;
}
```

And I finally got this exception "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": error=2, No such file or directory". What is the problem here?

Comment: Hi, could you please also post the error log?

Comment: Hello I just completed the post.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump": error=2, No such file or directory

This means that the shell is unable to find the executable file for "mysqldump". Try giving the entire absolute path to mysqldump inside your command like i.e. (assuming linux-like system):

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DBNAME > /path/to/location/backup.sql");
```

Exact path on Linux can usually be found using command `which mysqldump`

You could as well add this path to you PATH environment variable and keep your command as is (not 100% sure of this one as I'm usually working on Windows and am far from a Linux expert).

Comment: Hi I tried to add the absolute path into the command but I then got this error "mysqldump: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) when trying to connect".

Comment: It means you've moved one step forward. Now it's a matter of configuring mysqldump with the right command line, in which I'm mostly unqualified... Sorry (you are now actually calling mysqldump, but the connection details are wrong. Check socket/host/port/user/password)